# role="presentation" appears in Material-UI Icons for some users but not others, breaking snapshot tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, material-ui, wai-aria

In our project, we are using Material-UI Icons. However, something is breaking our tests. For me, when I run snapshot tests or look at the elements in the browser inspector, I do not see a `role="presentation"` prop on the elements. For everyone else, however, the role is present.

What I see

```js
<svg
  className="MuiSvgIcon-root"
  focusable="false"
  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
```

What everyone else in the project sees:

```js
<svg
  className="MuiSvgIcon-root"
  focusable="false"
  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
  aria-hidden="true"
  role="presentation"
>
```

I have no clue why. Furthermore, I am unable to reproduce this. I created a codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-elgamal-bxpk7?file=/src/App.js) to no avail.

Notes:
1. I am on Windows, they are on Macs
2. We all use Chrome browser
3. These differences appear when running Jest tests as well
4. We use `react-testing-library` for rendering components for Jest tests
5. I confirmed we all have the same version of `material-ui` installed

As an experiment, I had one of my colleagues hard-code an SVG into the page. When doing that, the `role` does not appear.

Looking through the [material-UI github](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui), I didn't see anywhere that `role="presentation"` would be set.

Has anyone heard of such a problem? I don't even know what else to investigate or check.

For reference, here's our packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.4.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "blob-stream": "^0.1.3",
    "chalk": "2.4.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "connected-react-router": "6.4.0",
    "cross-env": "5.2.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.10.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "4.16.4",
    "fontfaceobserver": "2.1.0",
    "formik": "^2.0.2",
    "history": "4.9.0",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "3.3.0",
    "immer": "3.0.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "invariant": "2.2.4",
    "ip": "1.1.5",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "minimist": "1.2.0",
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react-helmet": "6.0.0-beta",
    "react-intl": "2.8.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.1",
    "react-redux": "7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.0.1",
    "react-wordcloud": "^1.2.2",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "redux": "4.0.4",
    "redux-saga": "1.0.5",
    "reselect": "4.0.0",
    "sanitize.css": "11.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "7.2.0",
    "uswds": "2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "7.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.22",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.1.4",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "3.1.3",
    "axe-core": "^3.4.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "2.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "3.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.4.24",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "5.0.2",
    "compare-versions": "3.4.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0",
    "coveralls": "3.0.3",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "13.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "4.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "1.0.0",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "4.6.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.8.0",
    "jest-cli": "24.7.1",
    "jest-dom": "3.1.3",
    "lint-staged": "8.1.5",
    "ngrok": "3.1.1",
    "node-plop": "0.18.0",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "plop": "2.3.0",
    "pre-commit": "1.2.2",
    "prettier": "1.17.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "0.2.2",
    "react-axe": "^3.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "react-testing-library": "6.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "shelljs": "0.8.3",
    "@odw/fda-opioids-styleguide": "file:./../fda-opioids-styleguide",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "stylelint": "10.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "5.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "3.3.0",
    "stylelint-prettier": "1.1.1",
    "stylelint-scss": "3.9.4",
    "svg-url-loader": "2.3.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.2.3",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "webpack": "4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.6.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.24.3",
    "webpack-pwa-manifest": "4.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "3.0.0"
  }
```

Update 5/7/20: Still an issue. Still haven't been able to figure out what is causing it.